# How do I print two arrays using recursion, one after another (i.e. not concurrently)?

Tags: c, arrays, recursion

My code is posted as follows and currently prints out "1,6,2,7,3,8,4,9,5,10,DONE", in other words, it goes through and prints out the first arrays first element then the second arrays first element then the first arrays second and the second arrays second and so on and so forth (sorry for the run on sentence). I want an output of "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,DONE" so that the first array is completely printed, then the second array is too, then DONE is printed. **PLEASE KEEP RECURSION IN THIS FUNCTION** (I'm trying to understand the fundamentals of recursively calling a function):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 5
void printcombo(int* a, int* b)
{
    int first,second;
    first = *a;
    second = *b;    
    if (first != 0 && second !=0)
    {
        printf("%d,",first);
        printf("%d,",second);
        printcombo(a+1,b+1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("DONE\n");
    }

 }


int main()
{
    int a[N] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int b[N] = {6,7,8,9,10};
    printcombo(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

*I would appreciate it if only a small bit of the code was changed, but obviously do what you gotta do.*

Comment: Add a third argument which determines whether you should currently printing from `a` or `b`, and update it at the relevant time...

Comment: Not answering your question, but does your `if` condition works : `if (first != 0 && second !=0)` ?

Comment: yeah the if condition works, I know I'm assuming, this is just me messing around with recursion, so it really doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one variant:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 6

void printcombo(int* a, int* b)
{
    int first,second;
    first = *a;
    second = *b;
    if (first != 0) {
        printf("%d ", first);
        printcombo(a+1,b);
    } else if (second != 0) {
        printf("%d ", second);
        printcombo(a,b+1);
    } else {
        printf("DONE\n");
    }
 }


int main()
{
    int a[N] = {1,2,3,4,5,0};
    int b[N] = {6,7,8,9,10,0};
    printcombo(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's functionally little different from the solution I posted. It recurses once to print the first array, and then recurses a second time to print the second array. It's also far less efficient than any sane way of doing this. But hey, it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply have two separate invocations of your recursive function?

(I've also added zeros to the end of the arrays, since if you're checking for it you ought to put it there. It's bad form to assume.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 6
void printarray(int* n)
{
    int number;
    number = *n;
    if (number != 0)
    {
        printf("%d,",number);
        printcombo(n+1);
    }
}


int main()
{
    int a[N] = {1,2,3,4,5,0};
    int b[N] = {6,7,8,9,10,0};
    printarray(a);
    printarray(b);
    printf("DONE\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I get that I can just call it twice but if I want to keep it just with two arguements, I just want to know if I can do it that way...

Comment: Well there's a reasonable way to do it if you want to print your first array in order, and then your second array backwards. Otherwise, it's not really conducive to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 5

void printcombo(int* a, int* b){
    int first,second;
    first = *a;
    second = *b;
    if(first == 0 && second == 0){
        printf("DONE\n");
        return ;
    }
    if (first != 0 && second !=0){
        if(first < second){
            printf("%d,",first);
            ++a;
        } else {
            printf("%d,",second);
            ++b;
        }
    } else if (first != 0 && second == 0){
        printf("%d,",first);
        ++a;
    } else if (first == 0 && second != 0){
        printf("%d,",second);
        ++b ;
    }
    printcombo(a, b);
}

int main(){
    int a[N+1] = {1,2,3,4,5, 0};//last element is 0 and sorted
    int b[N+1] = {6,7,8,9,10, 0};
    printcombo(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```